# curve modifier and rotation values

Tags: curve-modifier

[image]I have a street pole and I want to create copies of it to follow a curve. If I apply an Array and a Curve modifier respectively, I end up with a single mesh of poles rotated along the path. However, if I apply the modifiers ,separate them "by Loose Parts" and set the origin to their geometry each pole is rotated in space but its z-rotation value is 0. Is there a way to retain the original rotation value of each pole in world space from curve modifier? or maybe a different approach than array and curve modifiers?

Comment: Please include an illustration? It would make the orientations you're talking about clearer.  See [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)?